# FileZilla : 550 CWD failed. Directory not found

Tags: video, browser, ftp, filezilla

I' trying to display a video that I have stored in an FTP server.

When I open a picture using my FTP address, it display fine, and I can see it.

But when I enter the video link, which is in the same ftp folder, nothing happens. The video exists and I can play it in my computer, but when I try to open it in a browser, using it's link, it doesn't show. I downloaded the html5 reader, I support flash ... other videos display well, but mine just doesn't.

When I check the FileZilla Server, I find the following messages :

```
(000133)16/05/2013 14:57:21 - (not logged in) (10.0.0.120)> Connected, sending welcome message...
(000133)16/05/2013 14:57:21 - (not logged in) (10.0.0.120)> 220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.41 beta
(000133)16/05/2013 14:57:21 - (not logged in) (10.0.0.120)> 220-written by Tim Kosse (Tim.Kosse@gmx.de)
(000133)16/05/2013 14:57:21 - (not logged in) (10.0.0.120)> 220 Please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/
(000133)16/05/2013 14:57:27 - (not logged in) (10.0.0.120)> USER ingenius
(000133)16/05/2013 14:57:27 - (not logged in) (10.0.0.120)> 331 Password required for ingenius
(000133)16/05/2013 14:57:33 - (not logged in) (10.0.0.120)> PASS ********
(000133)16/05/2013 14:57:33 - ingenius (10.0.0.120)> 230 Logged on
(000133)16/05/2013 14:57:41 - ingenius (10.0.0.120)> SYST
(000133)16/05/2013 14:57:41 - ingenius (10.0.0.120)> 215 UNIX emulated by FileZilla
(000133)16/05/2013 14:57:41 - ingenius (10.0.0.120)> PWD
(000133)16/05/2013 14:57:41 - ingenius (10.0.0.120)> 257 "/" is current directory.
(000133)16/05/2013 14:57:41 - ingenius (10.0.0.120)> TYPE I
(000133)16/05/2013 14:57:41 - ingenius (10.0.0.120)> 200 Type set to I
(000133)16/05/2013 14:57:41 - ingenius (10.0.0.120)> PASV
(000133)16/05/2013 14:57:41 - ingenius (10.0.0.120)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (10,0,0,120,205,239)
(000133)16/05/2013 14:57:41 - ingenius (10.0.0.120)> SIZE /IngeniusFTP/video-2013-05-09-18-05-34.ogg
(000133)16/05/2013 14:57:41 - ingenius (10.0.0.120)> 213 4589529
(000133)16/05/2013 14:57:41 - ingenius (10.0.0.120)> CWD /IngeniusFTP/video-2013-05-09-18-05-34.ogg
(000133)16/05/2013 14:57:41 - ingenius (10.0.0.120)> 550 CWD failed. "/IngeniusFTP/video-2013-05-09-18-05-34.ogg": directory not found.
(000133)16/05/2013 14:57:41 - ingenius (10.0.0.120)> PASV
(000133)16/05/2013 14:57:41 - ingenius (10.0.0.120)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (10,0,0,120,205,241)
(000133)16/05/2013 14:57:41 - ingenius (10.0.0.120)> RETR /IngeniusFTP/video-2013-05-09-18-05-34.ogg
(000133)16/05/2013 14:57:41 - ingenius (10.0.0.120)> 150 Connection accepted
(000133)16/05/2013 14:57:41 - ingenius (10.0.0.120)> disconnected.
(000133)16/05/2013 14:57:41 - ingenius (10.0.0.120)> 426 Connection closed; transfer aborted.
(000133)16/05/2013 14:57:41 - ingenius (10.0.0.120)> could not send reply, disconnected.
```

Am I missing something ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the video or the browser you are using, it is hard to tell what the problem is.

Reading the FTP log:

The `SIZE` first is likely just issued to figure out whether the item (your provided URI) actually exists at all. The server responded successfully and not with an error.

Next the `CWD`. The FTP client (your browser) simply tries to figure out what you have supplied - an URI to a file or to a directory. `CWD` failed, but `SIZE` succeeded, so the item is present and not directory - it is a file.

The client (browser) then uses `RETR` to actually read/stream the file.

Conclusion:

From an FTP point of view, it looks fine. The problem could be that the browser you are using does not support OGG as container format. Or it does support the OGG container, but neither the used audio and/or video codec.

Next steps:

Try to put the video in your local file system and browse to it using the `file:///` URI. If the video does not even load there, it is the browsers fault. If it loads, put the video on an HTTP server (webserver) and try again. HTTP is much easier (from a networking/firewall point of view) than FTP.